# Call to undefined function mysql_query_del() in

Tags: php, mysql

I am new in php and I'm trying to execute multiple query in a php file, and it gives me this error "Call to undefined function mysql_query_del() in" if I execute only one query it works but if I execute 2 or more queries then it's not working. Can someone help me with this please?

This is my code I want to execute.

I want it to delete the values from table after I transfer it to another table.

```php
<?php
//make connection
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
//select db
mysql_select_db('mjj_app');



$sql="INSERT INTO tbl1_viewer (fname,fqty) SELECT food,quantity FROM table1_orderlist;";
$list=mysql_query($sql);
?>


<?php

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($list){
$sqldel="DELETE * FROM table1_orderlist;";
$result=mysql_query_del(sqldel);
    if($result){
            header("Location: index.php");
    }
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

Comment: you really wanna do this: `DELETE * FROM table1_orderlist;` ? You sure?

Comment: ...and there is no `DELETE *`, you either delete a complete row or not. see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php

there is no such function like `mysql_query_del`

replace

```
$result=mysql_query_del(sqldel);
```

with

```
$result=mysql_query($sqldel);
```

also replace

```
$sql="INSERT INTO tbl1_viewer (fname,fqty) SELECT food,quantity FROM table1_orderlist;";
```

with

```
$sql="INSERT INTO tbl1_viewer (fname,fqty) (SELECT food,quantity FROM table1_orderlist)";
```

and as @Drew said
replace

```
$sqldel="DELETE * FROM table1_orderlist;";
```

with

```
$sqldel="DELETE FROM table1_orderlist;";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE * FROM table1_orderlist;
```

is a syntax error.

it should be

```
DELETE FROM table1_orderlist;
```

which will delete all the rows, if that is really what you want

Comment: no problem. It had already been established you were making the wrong function call to a non-existing one. Just wanted to warn you against losing all that data before you pulled the trigger. Good luck in all your coding and learning

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
$result=mysql_query_del(sqldel);
```

to:

```
$result=mysql_query($sqldel);
```

and use prepared statements PDO/MySQLi because your code is vulnerable to sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sqldel="DELETE * FROM table1_orderlist;";
$result=mysql_query_del(sqldel);
```

replace this line with it:

```
$sqldel="DELETE  FROM table1_orderlist;";
$result=mysql_query(sqldel);
```